# CSS Cascade HELP - Need child to override parent

Tags: css, css-selectors

i am defining color blocks...

```
.custom1 {
    background: red;
}
.custom1 h3 {
    color: white;
}
.custom2 {
    background: blue;
}
.custom2 h3 {
    color: #0f0;
}
.custom3 {
    background: #000;
}
.custom3 h3 {
    color: #f0f;
}
```

easy enough

my problem arises when my blocks nest within each other.

the top most parent wrapper declaration of the H3 overrides the child wrapper declaration of the H3 (which seems incorrect to me)

here is a little fiddle of my problem

http://jsfiddle.net/ujrLf/

adding the greater than sign ">" does fixes the problem, but only for the first level.

**how can i force the child element declarations to override the parent?**

Comment: To answer the last line: Increase the specifity of the selector. Google for the term if you don't know what it means. I have no clue what you want though, can you explain what you want to achieve? We don't know what consider incorrect (re "which seems incorrect to me").

Comment: An image of how it's supposed to look would help.

Comment: take a look at the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ujrLf/ i am displaying my 3 defined color blocks, then i an wrapping the same 3 blocks with each of the defined colors... idealy, each block of blocks should look the same on the inside

Comment: You should read this, [CSS Specificity for Poker Players](http://www.iamacamera.org/?id=95)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks to all that have tried. here is the solution i am going with...

here is the fiddle! http://jsfiddle.net/4wAtz/1/

```
.custom1 {
    background: red;
}
.custom1 h3, 
[class*='custom'] .custom1 h3,
[class*='custom'] [class*='custom'] .custom1 h3,
.and-so-on, .and-so-on, .and-you-get-it
{
    color: white;
}
.custom2 {
    background: blue;
}
.custom2 h3, 
[class*='custom'] .custom2 h3,
[class*='custom'] [class*='custom'] .custom2 h3
{
    color: #0f0;
}
.custom3 {
    background: #000;
}
.custom3 h3, 
[class*='custom'] .custom3 h3,
[class*='custom'] [class*='custom'] .custom3 h3
{
    color: #f0f;
}
```

it is not as elegant as i would like but it works! i just need to extrapolate for as many levels (plus 1) that i can see happening.

Comment: You should use Zeaklous's method shown in his fiddle that utilizes the direct child selector for each application. That is the "cleanest" solution.

Comment: unfortunately, the greater than symbol will only target the direct children. the content of any wrappers with in it would be untouched.

Comment: One or the other of us is misunderstanding something, but [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ujrLf/6/) has a wrapper `<span>` inside the `h3` that is still getting the color from that `h3` because `color` is inherited in CSS, so all the wrappers within an `h3` would still get that color even using the direct child selector only on the `h3` (because of inheritance). If you are referring to the `h3` itself being wrapped further, then I can see your point, but there is still a better solution. I'll post an answer for that.

Comment: that h3 is still on the child level... you would need to wrap the span around the h3 to lose the styling

Comment: not sure why you are getting the down votes! I gave you a +1 because this best answers your question.

Comment: I conceded :-). I agree, with the levels of wrapping you desire the css you propose appears to be the only answer. However, you had posted a non-working fiddle link, so I corrected that.

Answer (score 0):

Using > seemed to fix it as well, even on the further down levels. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/ujrLf/3/)

```
.custom1 > h3 {
    color: white;
}
.custom2 > h3 {
    color: #0f0;
}
.custom3 > h3 {
    color: #f0f;
}
```

You can also use `!important` on the lines where you want to override all other CSS commands **USE HESITANTLY, SEE COMMENTS FOR WHY** or you could increase specificity even more

Comment: you should read this: http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Comment: It's better to increase the specificity of the selector when you want to override.  There's a very specific order of precedence in CSS, and using !important will circumvent it. http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/

Comment: I realize `!important` isn't always to be used, but for his simple example it would work quite well

Comment: I didn't say to make them all !important, just the specific lines that he particularly wants to be a certain way

Answer (score 0):

When there are styles with the same level of specifity, they are used in the order read in. That's why when you have a ".custom3" wrapper, since it's the last one read in the list of styles, the ".custom3 h3" color trumps the ".custom1 h3" and ".custom2 h3" colors.

The more specific you can get, the higher priority those styles will have. For example, ".custom3 h3" will have a higher priority over just an "h3". And "#content .custom3 h3" would have a higher priority yet.

Comment: good reasoning for the why, but incorrect resolution as it relates to the question

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to give h3 the color. You can easily give the .custom1 class that same color which would eventually get applied to all its children.

Why don't you change the CSS to something like this ?

```
h3 {
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
[class*='custom'] {
    padding: 5px;
}
.custom1 {
    background: red;
    color: white;
}
.custom2 {
    background: blue;
    color: #0f0;
}
.custom3 {
    background: #000;
      color: #f0f;
}
```

Check the new fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ujrLf/4/

Comment: that would make my text and headers the same color.

Comment: I did not see any text that is outside the <h3> tag. Is that a possibility ?